# Pointers dereferencing when character arrays are passed

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wasnt touching C for quite a long time and these days decided to remind myself some stuff. I start watching Jerry Chain's lectures in Stanford and in one of his examples, in lecture 4 he implemented generic swap in C:

```
void swap(void* arg1, void* arg2, int len) {
  char buff[len];
  memcpy(buff, arg1, len);
  memcpy(arg1, arg2, len);
  memcpy(arg2, buff, len);
}
```

Everything in this function seems to be alright, however, once it was passed character arrays, with & everything seems to working. Without **&** in his examples, the console output was **Wilm and Freda**. However, on my side in both ways, the program is working perfectly.

```
  char* wife = strdup("Wilma");
  char* husband = strdup("Fred");

  cout<<husband<<endl<<wife<<endl;
  swap(&husband,&wife, sizeof(char*));
  cout<<husband<<endl<<wife<<endl;
```

So the question is, why it is working ? It should not work correctly. The & dereference pointer to the actual value, aka. character arrays. Without it should point to the pointer address itself.

The problem comes from this source: https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS107/200

Comment: If your program works, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it should not work correctly. The & dereference pointer to the actual value, aka. character arrays. Without it it should point to the pointer address itself.

Comment: @Neil Since when is `std::cout` a c feature?

Comment: The question should be , why do we need the `&` operator, at all? :)

Comment: @celeborn `swap(&husband,&wife, sizeof(char*));` is completely odd, and doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Actually, changes the pointers to both chars. As I said, this is not my example. it comes from here: https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS107/200

Comment: @celeborn Don't use code you don't fully understand from the interwebz. There's a good chance it's just awkward crap.

Comment: Either tag this C and change to use C code, or be aware that the correct answer will be: don't write code this way in c++.

Comment: Guys, this is a briliant question. No doubt. I mean it. James Poag gave the answer.

Comment: `&` is the address-of operator, not "dereference pointer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It should not work correctly.

Yes, it should.

> The & dereference pointer to the actual value, aka. character arrays

No. The dereference operator is `*`. `&` is the address-of operator.

> Without it should point to the pointer address itself.

No. The pointer points to the character array. The address-of expression points to the pointer variable.

> Without & in his examples, the console output was Wilm and Freda. However, on my side in both ways, the program is working perfectly.

At this point, it is important to remember that even if a program appears to behave as you intended, it doesn't necessarily *work perfectly*.

The exact behaviour of `swap(husband,wife, sizeof(char*));` will depend on the size of the pointer variable. If the pointer variable is larger than the size of the character array (5 is the smaller one), then the swap will copy the entire character arrays and overflow, resulting in undefined behaviour.

If the pointer variable is smaller than the size of the character array, then part of the array will not be copied, as demonstrated by your lecturer. On his system, the size of a data pointer is 4.

The given algorithm can only be used to swap two identically sized objects. It can not be used to swap contents of two arrays of different sizes, but it can be used to swap two pointers of same type.

---

Of course, it would be silly to use a custom generic swap implemented in C, when programming in C++. You could use `std::swap` instead - or a custom one optimized for your particular type.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well. Just wanted someone with more recent experience to confirm it. Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: `std::swap` does 3 moves, a construct and a destroy; often it's beneficial to write your own swap for a class

Answer (score 2):

On his machine, the size of a pointer is 4 bytes.  This is why "Wilm and Freda", because it is swapping the first four bytes (`sizeof(char*)`).

Since char* is a pointer to char array, you can either swap the pointers to these strings, or the memory pointed to by the strings.

If the Machine uses 64bit, then it is swapping the first 8 bytes, so the entire string and some garbage gets copied.

---

The const char string "Wilma" takes up 6 bytes (for null terminated).  E.g. ['W', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'a', '\0'].  "Fred" is similarly 5 bytes: ['F', 'r', 'e', 'd', '\0'].

If the memory is aligned, then it will probably look like this:

```
['W', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'a', '\0', *, *, |'F', 'r', 'e', 'd', '\0', *, *, *]
```

where `|` is the DWORD boundary and `*` is garbage.  64bits is 8 bytes, so you are probably swapping the entire memory section.

Comment: Oh, he's swapping the pointers to `char*`! So `sizeof(char*)` is absolutely valid.